# Still possible to add "Explanation for permissions" to Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

It used to be possible to add a short "Why is ExampleApp asking for these permissions?" blurb to extended permissions prompts for Facebook apps (for an example, see http://www.flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe/8571348851/).

As Facebook explains here (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/578/) "We’ve also introduced an area on the extended permissions screen that lets you explain why you need extended permissions."

I haven't seen a note on this being deprecated. There's still an "Explanation for Permissions" field in App Details, but any text typed there doesn't show up on the permissions prompt, and I can't figure out how to make it show.

Is it still possible to include this explanation?

Is getting it to show up somehow tied to submitting an App Detail page for review? (Seems odd that Facebook wouldn't let apps that hadn't submitted App Detail pages explain why they needed permissions, but I guess it's possible.)

I can't figure this out and I'd welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The "Explanation for Permissions" field displays on a user's App Settings page, under "This app can also".

Example:

Why is [APP NAME] asking for these permissions?
From [APP NAME]: [An explanation for how your application plans to use these extended permissions; 140 characters max.]